# GraphView: how to fit width tablet screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-graphview

I'm fighting with GraphView in my Android app since it doesn't fit my tablet screen width even if in smartphone screen it works. I used relative constraints so it should work. Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/browse"
        android:layout_width="233dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text="Scegli un segnale"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/line_graph2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/line_graph2" />

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/line_graph2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="383dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.546"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here what I get when i try it on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A P550):
[image: View on tablet Samung Galaxy A p550]

And here what I get in Pixel 3A emulated in Android Studio (however it's the same in my Honor 8)

[image: View on Google Pixel 3A]

I'm pretty new on Android Studio develpment. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
After I had followed Varsha Godage instruction I modified this way my xml and I get the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/browse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text="Scegli un segnale"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line_graph2" />

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/line_graph2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I get the same result using this virtual machine:

> Name: New_Device_API_30
>
> CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Path: /home/samastel/.android/avd/New_Device_API_30.avd
>
> Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 30)
>
> Skin: galaxy_nexus
>
> fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> hw.lcd.height: 768
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: New Device
>
> vm.heapSize: 48
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: User
>
> hw.lcd.width: 1024
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 30
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
>
> tag.id: google_apis
>
> showDeviceFrame: yes
>
> hw.camera.back: virtualscene
>
> hw.mainKeys: yes
>
> AvdId: New_Device_API_30
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> hw.lcd.density: 120
>
> avd.ini.displayname: New Device API 30
>
> hw.arc: false
>
> hw.gpu.mode: auto
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:5131845cdecd82a7945a092e26ede305
>
> fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
>
> fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
>
> hw.ramSize: 1536
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> PlayStore.enabled: false
>
> fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google APIs
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: no
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

[image: Updated version]

**Update N 2**

Here there is my Java code of the interface

```
package com.example.ble.ui.grafici;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.ble.AppUtilis;
import com.example.ble.MainActivity4;
import com.example.ble.R;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import java.util.List;

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {


    private Button browser;
    private AppUtilis util;
    private String path;
    private View root;
    private GraphicModel model;

    //private Fragment fSys;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GraphicModel.class);
        model.getLiveSign().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), liveSign -> {
            draw(liveSign);
        });
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        // fSys = (Fragment) browser.findViewById(R.id.fragment2);
        util = new AppUtilis(this.getContext());
        path = "";//setto il path a niente poi quando torno indietro torno il nulla e chiaramente dovrò bypassare
        browser = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.browse);
        browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(util.getContext(), MainActivity4.class);
                System.out.println("Vado a cercare roba");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
        });


        return root;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            path = data.getStringExtra("PATH");

            if (!path.equals("")) {
                //apri cose
                model.loadCSV(path);
                System.out.println(path);
            }


        }
    }
    //sarebbe carino salvarlo se si cambia schermata
    private void draw(List<Integer> sign) {
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) root.findViewById(R.id.line_graph2);
        graph.removeAllSeries();
        System.out.println(sign.size());

        if (sign.size() > 0) {
            LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < sign.size(); i++) {
                DataPoint point = new DataPoint(i, sign.get(i));
                series.appendData(point, true, sign.size());
            }
            graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
            graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
            series.setThickness(3);

            graph.addSeries(series);

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happening as GraphView width is set to wrap_content and height is fixed. To make it resizable based on screen size set width to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`  and height to  `android:layout_height="0dp"` and define percentage of height you want this graph view to cover using `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"` (with 0.6, height will be 60% of the screen height).

Comment: Thank you . I tried and I get the same result. From my previus xml code i only added/changed the three line you said but in tablet screen the result is still the same...

Comment: Can you post your updated xml ? I tried changing width and height attributes as motioned above comment and it seems to work fine for me . Also you are not changing any attributes for GraphView in code right?

Comment: Yes i updated my post. I posted  also the references of a virtual machine that gives me the same problem as on the real tablet, if you want to try

Comment: Its working fine for me with your xml so I don't think there is any problem with layout. Can you post your DashboardFragment just to make sure if its something in the code itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick feedback, sorry if I'm late, I've updated again my question with the interfaces Java Code

Comment: Sorry for late response , but I could not find anything wrong in the code as well , its working perfectly fine for me.(I am using GraphView version 4.2.2)

Comment: Thank you so much maybe I have to update something, my version is 4.2.1